# AJAX - Can't access success method of JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm try to trigger ajax call when page refresh and after refresh I want do some change of the page content according to data that get by the ajax call but with my script I can't access the success method of jquery function but function pass the data to the servlet. I used other ajax call script block with same servlet then it correctly return the data to the success method, I mean my servlet pass the data correctly, it's not work only for this JavaScript function, seems to be there is problem with my JavaScript function but i can't find it.Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

I am using mata tag for refresh the page

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
```

And this is the JavaScript function

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
    var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload';

    myEvent(chkevent, function (e) {
        var divIds = [];
        $('input.reloadPage').each(function() {
            if($(this).val() == "y"){
                divIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
            }

         });          

            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                //traditional: true,
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                url: 'reloadReverseAuction.do',
                data: {
                    divIds : divIds
                  },

                success: function (data) {
                  $.growl.notice({ message: data.relodeList});
                  var idList = data.relodeList;

                  $.each(idList,function(idx,obj){
                      $("#check-interest_"+obj).css("display", "block");
                  });

                },
                error: function(e){
                    $.growl.error({ message: e});
                }
            }); 
        });  
  });
```

Comment: If you put a `console.log` statement inside the `success` function, is it called?

Comment: no it's also not call.

Comment: I think I can't access the success method because of page is reloaded when ajax call come back to the page